# Bash: How to extract numbers preceded by _ and followed by

Tags: string, bash, extract

I have the following format for filenames: `filename_1234.svg`

How can I retrieve the numbers preceded by an underscore and followed by a dot. There can be between one to four numbers before the `.svg`

I have tried:

> ```
> width=${fileName//[^0-9]/}
> ```

but if the fileName contains a number as well, it will return all numbers in the filename, e.g.

```
file6name_1234.svg
```

I found solutions for two underscores (and splitting it into an array), but I am looking for a way to check for the underscore as well as the dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple *parameter expansion with substring removal* to simply trim from the *right* up to, and including, the `'.'`, then trim from the *left* up to, and including, the `'_'`, leaving the number you desire, e.g.

```
$ width=filename_1234.svg; val="${width%.*}"; val="${val##*_}"; echo $val
1234
```

**note:** `#` trims from *left* to *first-occurrence* while `##` trims to *last-occurrence*. `%` and `%%` work the same way from the *right*.

Explained:

- `width=filename_1234.svg` - `width` holds your filename
- `val="${width%.*}"` - `val` holds `filename_1234`
- `val="${val##*_}"` - finally `val` holds `1234`

Of course, there is no need to use a temporary value like `val` if your intent is that `width` should hold the width. I just used a temp to protect against changing the original contents of `width`. If you want the resulting number in `width`, just replace `val` with `width` everywhere above and operate directly on `width`.

**note 2:** using shell capabilities like *parameter expansion* prevents creating a separate subshell and spawning a separate process that occurs when using a utility like `sed`, `grep` or `awk` (or anything that isn't part of the shell for that matter).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code :

```
filename="filename_6_1234.svg"
if [[ "$filename" =~ ^(.*)_([^.]*)\..*$ ]];
then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}" #will display 'filename_6_1234.svg'
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" #will display 'filename_6'
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" #will display '1234'
fi
```

Explanation :

- `=~` : bash operator for regex comparison
- `^(.*)_([^.])\..*$` : we look for any character, followed by an underscore, followed by any character, followed by a dot and an extension. We create 2 capture groups, one for before the last underscore, one for after
- `BASH_REMATCH` : array containing the captured groups

Comment: If I run this code I get: e_1 and e. Also if the filename contains another underscore, lets say: file6_name_1234.svg it outputs: 6_n and 6 (even though it does not fit the patter: underscore-digits-dot -> extract the digits) Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some more way

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ filename=file1b2aname_1234.svg
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ after=${filename##*_}
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ echo ${after//[^0-9]}
1234
```

Using `awk`

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk -F'[_.]' '{print $2}' <<< "$filename"
1234
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
sed 's!_! !g' | awk '{print "_" $NF}'
```

to get from filename_1234.svg to _1234.svg then

```
sed 's!svg!!g'
```

to get rid of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `IFS`, you can use Bash's build-in `read`.

This splits the filename by underscores and dots and stores the result in the array `a`.

```
IFS='_.' read -a a <<<'file1b2aname_1234.svg'
```

And this takes the second last element from the array.

```
echo ${a[-2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution using cut:

```
name="file6name_1234.svg"
num=$(echo "$name" | cut -d '_' -f 2 | cut -d '.' -f 1)
echo "$num"
```

`-d` is for specifying a delimiter.

`-f` refers to the desired field.

I don't know anything about performance but it's simple to understand and simple to maintain.